# How to increase the size of footnote counters used

Tags: footnotes, fontsize

I am writing a document in LaTeX for someone who is visually impaired, which means that I have to increase the font sizes for them. How do I increase the size of the font used for the footnote counter.

When used with the `footmisc` package, `\renewcommand\footnotelayout{\Large}` increases the size of the font used for the content of a footnote, but it does not increase the size of the footnote counter. How can I do this please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 6):

You can redefine the footnote counter printing macro `\thefootnote`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\textheight}{100pt}% Just for this example
\usepackage{footmisc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc
\usepackage{relsize}% http://ctan.org/pkg/relsize
\renewcommand\footnotelayout{\Large}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\larger[2]\arabic{footnote}}%
\begin{document}
Here is some text\footnote{This is a footnote} and some more text.
\end{document}
```

I've used [`relsize`](http://ctan.org/pkg/relsize) that provides `\smaller[<i>]` and `\larger[<i>]` to decrease/increase the font size by `<i>` steps. Although this is not necessary, it merely shows what can be done. Alternatively, you can also just use

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\large\arabic{footnote}}
```

where `\large` is the font size you want.